# c++ Can`t get all the child nodes from XML

Tags: c++, xml, collections, msxml

Consider the following code

```
CXmlDomNodeList oNodeList = m_oInputXmlData.pXmlDomRecvd->GetElementsByTagName("check_info");

for (CXmlDomNode oCheckNode = oNodeList.First(); oCheckNode; oCheckNode = oNodeList.Next())
{
    i64CheckId = _atoi64(oCheckNode.GetChildNodeText("check_id"));


 // do some stuff
 }
```

When i try to read all the elements in XML collection i read only the first number in the tag check_id, and skips the rest .. i'm trying to deal with this problem for 2 days now and i need your help.
 Here is the XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<iserver_request>
 <command>1603</command>
 <session>175395b931bf265ef9b6632fea48b060</session>
 <check_info>
  <check_id>166123</check_id>
  <check_id>16123</check_id>
  <check_id>1266</check_id>
  <check_id>1636</check_id>
  <check_id>1646</check_id>
  <check_id>1656</check_id>
 </check_info>
</iserver_request>
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What framework/library are you using to parse and handle the XML? Please edit your tags to add it.

Comment: i'm using the MSXML lib

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i fixed this my self and i am posting the answer in case somebody has the same problem

```
CXmlDomNodeList oNodeList = m_oInputXmlData.pXmlDomRecvd->GetElementsByTagName("check_id");

for (CXmlDomNode oCheckNode = oNodeList.First(); oCheckNode; oCheckNode = oNodeList.Next())
{
    i64CheckId = _atoi64(oCheckNode.GetText());

 //do stuff

 }
```

That's how i got all the element in the tag check_id.